# Why the SOSL doesn't get what it needs?

Tags: apex, sosl

### SOSL

```
String searchword ='Red';
String searchStr1 = '*'+searchword+'*';
String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchStr1 + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Product2(Id,Name)';
List<List<sObject>> searchConLead = search.query(searchQuery);
System.debug('searchConLead: '+searchConLead);
```

I need to get all the products that contain word "Red"

Comment: Is the word red in a custom rich text area field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOSL only supports "starts with" matching, as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm):

> Asterisks match zero or more characters at the middle or end of your search term
>
> Question marks match only one character in the middle or end of your search term

It isn't valid to put a wildcard at the start of the SOSL search term.

SOQL's % wildcard can be used at the start, in the middle and at the end of a search term, but clearly that is a different query technology and doesn't work for Shield Platform Encrypted fields (unlike SOSL).